# 17 year old son decided he is a girl but previous to coming out has never shown signs of feminine behavior

Tags: parents, communication, adult-child, lgbtq, transition

My now 18 year old son came out as transgender six months ago. He has never been girly. He is a stinky teenage boy, who does not clean his room, has to be forced to bathe and his voice and manner of speech are masculine. He does not walk or talk feminine. He has started wearing stuffed bras and girl tops and wants to be called by his girl name. What about college and career? Can I do anything without making this worse? I guess he expects me to support him financially forever? I was going to pay for his college, but don't want to throw a fortune into the garbage if he is not going to need or use his degree. And I am concerned that these institutions are no longer educating but indoctrinating. Any advise? How do I talk to him/her?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132913/discussion-on-question-by-user41257-17-year-old-son-decided-he-is-a-girl-but-pre).

Answer (score 7):

#### Take them to see psychologist.

You're not a psychologist, and neither is anyone here - and even if we were, we wouldn't be able to diagnose your child from a brief post on the internet.

However, a psychologist should be able to tell if your child is genuinely transgender, if they have some sort of sexual fetish for women's clothes, or if it's a phase they're going through because it's trendy at their university or something.  Once they've determined the root cause of this behaviour, they should be able to help you and your child to chart a path forward, whether that's transitioning, psychological counselling, or a referral to other specialists.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126228/discussion-on-answer-by-nick012000-17-year-old-son-decided-he-is-a-girl-but-prev).